# YII2 Getting unknown property: dev24\modules\reports\components\ReportDto::Value

Tags: yii2

YII2 Getting unknown property: dev24\modules\reports\components\ReportDto::Value
Please explain me why I get this error when I create migration to create report
This is my code of migration

```
protected $_reportService;

public function __construct($config = [])
{
    parent::__construct($config);

    $this->_reportService = new ReportService();
}

public function up()
{
    $this->registerAllConsultants();
}

protected function registerAllConsultants()
{
    $this->_reportService
        ->registerReport(
            'AllConsultantsReport',
            'Консультанты: Отчет по всем консультантам и их уровням',
            $desc = 'Отчет по всем консультантам и их уровням',
            new ReportConfiguration([
                ReportConfiguration::FIELD_PRE_SQL => [],
                ReportConfiguration::FIELD_COLUMNS => [
                    'Value' => [
                        'class' => \kartik\grid\DataColumn::class,
                        'attribute' => 'Value',
                        'pageSummary' => true,
                        'pageSummaryFunc' => GridView::F_SUM,
                        'pageSummaryOptions' => [
                            'prepend' => 'All Consultants Report: '
                        ]
                    ]
                ],

                ReportConfiguration::FIELD_SQL =>
                    ' SELECT  a.first_name,
                      a.last_name,
                      a.email,
                      a.phone,
                      b.level,
                      b.user_id
                      from passport a
                      INNER JOIN user c
                      ON a.id=c.passport_id
                      INNER JOIN consultant b
                      ON b.user_id=c.id
                    where
                        c.id = :user_id
                    and
                    b.create_time between UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(:begin_date,"%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00")) and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(:end_date ,"%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59"))

                  '
            ]),
            (new OptionFormBuilder())
                ->model(UserIdDateRangeFilter::class)
                ->hint($desc)
                ->mergeFields(UserIdDateRangeFilter::getFormConfig())
                ->build(),
            'Consultants'
        );
}
```

And this is error
If you need to see all list of error tell me please I will print
http://prntscr.com/gwvvsc
When I use dates period in which there is no consultant I get the empty report And didnt have such error

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. [Don't post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: which report module  you are using ?